# Citus Sharding balance info

Tags: database, postgresql, citus

I configured Citus cluster with 3 nodes, and created a few tabled and used function "create reference table". in this case able to get data (read) from other available nodes. But when one of the node got down unable to insert and unable to create reference table of newly created tables. in the cluster.

is there any solution to overcome that.

Thanks.

Comment: citus cluster gives to you ability to use sharding (ie to distribute your tables by multiple nodes).
if you need to get fault tolerance, then you need to add more nodes as hot standby replicas and setup some kind of fault-tolerance solution, like patroni, or repmgr, or whatever...

as initial example for docker/podman environment (easy to lauch for tests if you good enough with docker/podman) you may check that repo (linked below), look at readme and docker-compose-citus.yml.

https://github.com/zalando/patroni